# Best practice for storing millions of rows with TSQL (Sql Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

To start off, I'm not that great with database strategies, so I don't know really how to even approach this.

What I want to do is store some info in a database.  Essentially the data is going to look like this

> - **SensorNumber** (int)
> - **Reading**      (int)
> - **Timestamp**    (Datetime?)(I just want to track down to the minute, nothing further is needed)

The only thing about this is that over a few months of tracking I'm going to have millions of rows (~5 million rows).

I really only care about searching by Timestamp and/or SensorNumber.  The data in here is pretty much going to be never edited (insert once, read many times).

How should I go about building this?  Is there anything special I should do other than create the table?  and create the one index for SensorNumber and Temp?

Comment: You need to explain what your query patterns will be, since you seem to contradict  yourself in the question.

Comment: Your right JNK, I meant that I am only going to search by Sensor and/or timestamp

Comment: Will it always be `SENSOR` and sometimes also `timestamp` (bad name for a field, BTW), or will it sometimes be timestamp alone?

Comment: No best practice needed. This is still smlall stuff. Like really small. Try 20 billion rows ;)

Comment: @TomTom - I agree but 5m rows on a database that's not on a dedicated server could be a lot still, and would need some sort of thought put into indexing

Comment: It will almost always be Sensor + Timestamp

Comment: Ok, so millions is small stuff then for a database?  (I did say I wasn't great with this)

Comment: For a lot of scenarios, millions of rows is small.  It depends on your server setup, and access patterns, and a hundred other variables.  On its own a million rows isn't an issue.  I have tables that are  billions of rows and multiple terrabytes. These also run on very powerful dedicated servers, with expensive disk arrays and 10GB network cards, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: For only 3 fields though, and all of them being very narrow like this, a 5m rows you are only looking at like 80mb of data.

Comment: Yes. Even 200mb of data are noot necesarily a problem with AN index. That is why my comment. it cn be a lot, but then a lot depends on usage patterns and data distribution.

Comment: Timestamp is a reserved word in SDQL Server. DO NOT use it as a field name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comment, I would put a clustered index on `(Sensor, Timestamp)`.

This will always cover when you want to search for SENSOR alone, but will also cover both fields checked in combination.

If you want to ever search for `Timestamp` alone, you can add a nonclustered index there as well.

One issue you will have with this design is the need to rebuild the table since you are going to be inserting rows non-sequentially - the new rows won't always belong at the end of the index.

Also, please do not name a field `timestamp` - this is a keyword in SQL Server and can cause you all kinds of issues if you don't delimit it everywhere.

Comment: Ill come up with a better name for my datetime field.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You definitely want to use a SQL-Server "[clustered index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933131%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)" for the *most selective* data you're likely to search on.

Here's more info:

- http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/clustered-indexes/
- http://odetocode.com/articles/70.aspx
- http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2002/index-not-equal/

ELABORATION:

- "Sensor" would be a poor choice - you're likely to have few sensors, many rows.  This would *not* be a discriminating index.
- "Time" would be discriminating... but it would also be a poor choice.  Because the time itself, independent of sensor, temperature, etc, is probably meaningless to your query.
- A clustered index on "sensor,time" might be ideal.  Or maybe not - it depends on what you're after.
- Please review the above links.

PS:

Please, too, consider using "datetime" instead of "timestamp".  They're two completely different types under MSSQL ... and "datetime" is arguably the better, more flexible choice:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/timestamps-vs-datetime-data-types

Comment: Because "clustered index" is a Microsoft SQL-Server specific term ;)

Comment: @JNK I got a kick out of that comment.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with using a clustered index, you are almost certainly going to end up with one anyway - so it's better to define it.

A clustered index determines the order that the data is stored, adding to the end is cheaper than inserting into the middle.

Think of a deck of cards you are trying to keep in rank order as you add cards. If the highest rank is a 8, adding a 9 is trivial - put it at the top. 
If you add a 5, it gets more complex, you have to work out where to put it and then insert it.

So adding items with a clustered index in order is optimal.

Given that I would suggest having a clustered index in (Timestamp,Sensor).

Clustering on (Sensor, Timestamp) will create a LOT of changes to the physical ordering of data which is very expensive (even using SSD).

If Timestamp,Sensor combo is unique then define it as being UNIQUE, otherwise Sql Server will add in a uniqueidentifier on the index to resolve duplicates.

Primary keys are automatically unique, almost all tables should have a primary key.

If (Timestamp,Sensor) is not unique, or you want to reference this data from another table, consider using an identity column as the clustered Primary Key.

Good Luck!